# SignalR multiple requests

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr

I'm new to the forum and in the "world" of programming. I bumped into a problem while creating a game with SignalR Web technology and it is expressed in terms of access to the database (using EF) with multiple requests from UI-a. What is the best solution using the repository pattern? The decision to me at this stage is added Lock {} structure in each method, which accesses the database. How can I avoid blocking requests to a server?

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
   {
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(object id);
    void Add(T item);
    void Update(T item);      
    void Delete(T item);
    void Delete(object id);
  }


  public class DBRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DbContext DbContext;
    private DbSet<T> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            return this.DbContext.Set<T>();
        }
    }

    public DBRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.DbContext = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Entities.AsQueryable();
    }
 .....

  public class TicTacToeContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Guess> Guesses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MessageState> MessageStates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MessageType> MessageTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public TicTacToeContext()
        : base("TicTacToeDb")
    {
    }
 public interface IGameService
{
    void CreateGame(CreateGameModel gameModel);
    void JoinGame(JoinGameModel gameModel);
  ...
 public abstract class BaseService
{

    public IRepository<User> UserRepository;
    public  IRepository<Game> GameRepository;
...
  public class GameService : BaseService, IGameService
{

        public GameService(IRepository<Game> gameRepositort, IRepository<User>            userRepository, ISessionService sessionService)
    {
        this.UserRepository = userRepository;
        this.GameRepository = gameRepositort;

    }

    public void CreateGame(CreateGameModel gameModel)
    {
       ....
    }
  public class TicTacToeHub : Hub
{
    IUserService UserServise;
    IGameService GameServise;
    private static object _syncRoot = new object();
    public TicTacToeHub(IUserService userService, IGameService gameService)
    {
        this.UserServise = userService;
        this.GameServise = gameService;
    }
   .....


    public void ReturnOpenGamesToClient(string sessionKey)
    {
        IEnumerable<GameModel> openGames;
        lock (_syncRoot)
       {
           openGames = GameServise.GetOpenGames(sessionKey).ToList();
       }
        Clients.Caller.updateOpenGamesList(openGames);            
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to lock?  What's the situation you're trying to prevent (and why do you think you need to prevent it)?  Most DB technologies handle concurrency themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Why locks? You use a DB and only update one entity (No transaction scope needed).

Locks needs to be used for Inmemory types like IList or IDictionary otherwise it will crash when one request reads and another one writes. But SQL takes care of this for you

Comment: Thank you for answers.But but if I do not use Lock, get:
ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open...
Invalid operation. The connection is closed...
I use this depemdanci 
      IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<ISessionService>().To<SessionService>();               kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(DBRepository<>)).WithConstructorArgument("context",new TicTacToeContext());
            kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
            kernel.Bind<IGameService>().To<GameService>();

Comment: You use per connection Context, for example by using Ninject and InRequestScope